# More helpful network error

Tags: 12.04, networking, 64-bit

In Ubuntu, when my network fails to connect, it just says "network not connected / disconnected", without providing any helpful error message. On the contrary, Windows gives an error code plus a one or two line spanning error message that pinpoints what error occurred during a connection attempt. Is there a way to get such a detailed error report on Ubuntu, either via GUI or via terminal? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In all Linux Distros, you have access to the information you want.

You can do the follow, reading the system log file, to get the information you want:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

The result will be something like this:

```
Sep 27 13:36:50 Pluto NetworkManager[841]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) started...

Sep 27 13:36:50 Pluto avahi-daemon[845]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.51.

Sep 27 13:36:50 Pluto avahi-daemon[845]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.

Sep 27 13:36:50 Pluto avahi-daemon[845]: Registering new address record for 192.168.0.51 on eth0.IPv4.

Sep 27 13:36:51 Pluto NetworkManager[841]: <info> (eth0): device state change: ip-config -> activated (reason 'none') [70 100 0]

Sep 27 13:36:52 Pluto NetworkManager[841]: <info> Policy set 'Wired connection 1' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.

Sep 27 13:36:52 Pluto NetworkManager[841]: <info> Activation (eth0) successful, device activated.

Sep 27 13:36:52 Pluto NetworkManager[841]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) complete.

Sep 27 13:36:52 Pluto NetworkManager[841]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IP4 Configure Get) complete.

Sep 27 13:37:00 Pluto ntpdate[2445]: adjust time server 91.189.94.4 offset -0.108144
```

**To view the Log Files in a GUI:**

```
Click on System -> Administration -> Log File Viewer, to launch the GUI log viewer tool.
```

**NOTE:** If you can't find the System Log Viewer, open Synaptic Package Manager, and install "gnome-system-log".

[image: Log File Viewer]

Comment: Thank you. By any chance, is this information available via the some graphical front end, for users who don't want to do it at terminal? (asking for a friend)